# horizontal radio buttons using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align radio buttons horizontally in a form, using bootstrap.
Without adding the bootstrap library, this code works:

```
<form id="test_form">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label for="Q1">First question</label>
      <label for="Q1RB" class="radio">
        <input id="Q1RB" type="radio" name="Q1RB" value="Almost never" class="radio inline">Almost never
      </label>
      <label for="Q1RB" class="radio">
        <input id="Q1RB" type="radio" name="Q1RB" value="Sometimes" class="radio inline">Sometimes
      </label>
      <label for="Q1RB" class="radio">
        <input id="Q1RB" type="radio" name="Q1RB" value="Often" class="radio inline">Often
      </label>
      <label for="Q1RB" class="radio">
        <input id="Q1RB" type="radio" name="Q1RB" value="Almost always" class="radio inline">Almost always
      </label>
  </div>
</form
```

But after adding the bootstrap.js to the header, the radio buttons aren't aligned horizontally anymore, but vertically.
I'm using the last version of bootstrap (3.1.1)

Comment: Ok, I found an answer. Instead if using the "radio inline" class for each input, I added the "form-inline" class to the question div:
<div class="control-group form-inline">

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `radio-inline` class in your radio labels (see [this link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls)).

This happens because, by default, bootstrap uses a stacked layout.